# Replacing duplicate images in PDF files

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying to replace the duplicate images with available images in PDF file, but the result is corrupted.
`PdfReader.KillIndirect` nulls the duplicate image, but `writer.AddDirectImageSimple` won't replace it with the reference of the previously available image. What's the problem here?

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace ReplaceDuplicateImages
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Adding one image, 2 times.
        /// </summary>
        private static void createSampleFile()
        {
            using (var pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4))
            {
                var pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, new FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create));
                pdfDoc.Open();

                var table = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 1, 2 });
                table.AddCell(Image.GetInstance("01.png")); 
                table.AddCell(Image.GetInstance("01.png"));
                pdfDoc.Add(table);
            }
        }

        private static void RemoveDuplicateImagesFromPdfFile(string inFile, string outFile)
        {
            var pdfReader = new PdfReader(inFile);
            var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create));
            var writer = pdfStamper.Writer;

            var md5Service = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            var enc = new UTF8Encoding();
            var imagesDictionary = new Dictionary<string, PRIndirectReference>();

            int pageNum = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
            for (int i = 1; i <= pageNum; i++)
            {
                var page = pdfReader.GetPageN(i);
                var resources = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(page.Get(PdfName.RESOURCES)) as PdfDictionary;
                if (resources == null) continue;

                var xObject = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(resources.Get(PdfName.XOBJECT)) as PdfDictionary;
                if (xObject == null) continue;

                foreach (var name in xObject.Keys)
                {
                    var pdfObject = xObject.Get(name);
                    if (!pdfObject.IsIndirect()) continue;

                    var imgObject = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(pdfObject) as PdfDictionary;
                    if (imgObject == null) continue;

                    var subType = PdfReader.GetPdfObject(imgObject.Get(PdfName.SUBTYPE)) as PdfName;
                    if (subType == null) continue;

                    if (!PdfName.IMAGE.Equals(subType)) continue;

                    var imageBytes = PdfReader.GetStreamBytesRaw((PRStream)imgObject);
                    var md5 = enc.GetString(md5Service.ComputeHash(imageBytes));

                    if (!imagesDictionary.ContainsKey(md5)) // is it duplicate?
                    {
                        imagesDictionary.Add(md5, (PRIndirectReference)pdfObject);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        PdfReader.KillIndirect(pdfObject); // nulls the duplicate image

                        // trying to replace it with the reference of the available image
                        var imageRef = imagesDictionary[md5];
                        var image = Image.GetInstance(imageRef);
                        Image maskImage = image.ImageMask; // it's always null here.
                        if (maskImage != null)
                            writer.AddDirectImageSimple(maskImage);
                        writer.AddDirectImageSimple(image, (PRIndirectReference)pdfObject);
                    }
                }
            }

            pdfReader.RemoveUnusedObjects();
            pdfReader.Close();
            pdfStamper.Close();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            createSampleFile();
            RemoveDuplicateImagesFromPdfFile("test.pdf", "Optimized.pdf");
            Process.Start("Optimized.pdf");
        }
    }
}
```

I am aware of `PdfCopy` and `PdfSmartCopy`. I don't want to use them.

Comment: What are you seeing?  What is the output?

Comment: I told that, "the result is corrupted". first image is ok, but the second one is eliminated completely and Adobe reader shows an error message about this corrupted file.

Comment: Please explain why you do not want to use `PdfSmartCopy`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove redundant information (duplicate images, duplicate XObjects, duplicate fonts,...), please don't reinvent the wheel by trying to use iTextSharp's low-level functionality. Use PdfSmartCopy instead, and it will do all the difficult work for you.

The main problem with your code is that you remove duplicate images, but you never update the reference to those images. By doing so, you break the PDF.

Suppose that you have a PDF that contains two images that are identical (bytewise), and that are stored redundantly (the same bytes are in the PDF twice). Assume that the objects have the following references: `10 0 R` (first image) and `20 0 R` (second image).

You loop over the Image XObjects of every page, and you encounter `10 0 R`. You *keep* that image, and you store an MD5 hash of it:

```
imagesDictionary.Add(md5, (PRIndirectReference)pdfObject);
```

Then you encounter `20 0 R`. You discover that this image is identical to `10 0 R` because the md5 hash of both images corresponds. You remove that image `20 0 R`:

```
PdfReader.KillIndirect(pdfObject);
```

And then you do something that is really strange. Instead of changing the reference to the duplicate image (`20 0 R`) to the reference of the first instance of the image (`10 0 R`), you get that first instance (`image`) and you add it anew with its original reference (`10 0 R`):

```
writer.AddDirectImageSimple(image, (PRIndirectReference)pdfObject);
```

In other words: you try to add a second object with object number 10 to the PDF, which is illegal (each object number is unique). iText will ignore that line; It will just return the original `PdfName` that was used for the image.

Eventually, you end up with a PDF that has an image that references correctly to `10 0 R` and an image that references to `20 0 R` which points at an object that no longer exists because you removed the image with object number 20.

That explains the problem you experience, and that you described as:

> "the result is corrupted". first image is ok, but the second one is eliminated completely and Adobe reader shows an error message about this corrupted file.